# Why nodes enable hotkey in UE5 not working?

Tags: unreal-engine5

[image]

[image]

I set it the key disabled node for 'M'
and enabled node for 'N' hotkey

But It's not working for enable node 'N'.
'M' works well.
What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It works when I changed the hotkey for 'Enable Nodes' to 'Enable Nodes(Always)'